# Joomla 4 - how to override config.xml of com_users component

Tags: joomla4

I am trying to add extra fields to com_users's config.xml. I managed to do it by adding them directly to config.xml. However, if I update to the next available Joomla 4 version, I will lose all the additional fields I have added to config.xml. I have also tried creating an override in /administrator/templates/atum/com_users/config.xml, but it is not working.

Thanks in advance.